# Google Chrome - Developer Tools - Network Panel

Tags: google-chrome

When I check my network panel in the Google Chrome dev tools, in the column labelled
**Size**
Content

I find something like this
**Size**     47.19KB
**Content**      572.92KB

Which one of this the actual data transferred? This is important to me as I use GAE and want to use every last drop of the 1MB per call limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Size` is the number of bytes actually transferred; so it reflects any response compression you're using.